# Codeigniter Set variable

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a controller named `categories` in which I have

```
function description($id=null) {
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->view('category/description');
    $this->load->model('userdata_model');
    $data = $this->userdata_model->desc($id);
    $this->load->view('category/description', $data);
}
```

Now when I do `print_r($data);` it gives me the following result

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4481
            [title] => Dvd Recorder Post
            [image_name] => 
            [image_name_work] => 
            [video_name] => 
            [work_type] => tape-recrder
            [description] => Test first..
            [agency] => 
            [services] => 
            [photographer] => 
            [company] => 
            [director] => 
            [dop] => 
            [userid] => 
            [display_order] => 99999
            [latest_work] => No
            [status] => Active
            [post_adddate] => 2012-03-26 10:14:07
            [date] => 2012-03-26 10:14:07
            [sub_cat] => dvd-reorder
            [views] => 75
            [url] => Dvd-recorder-post
            [post_cache] => 
            [post_cat_id] => 0
            [post_link] => 
            [post_pubdate] => 
            [post_seo_url] => 
            [post_status] => 0
            [post_type] => 0
        )

)
```

Now when I try to access `$data` in `description.php` in the view page it gives me following error

> ```
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: data
>
> Filename: category/description.php
>
> Line Number: 2
> ```

Anybody has an idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter uses [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) to generate the variables in the view page. So, you'll have to pass in an associative array as the second argument of the `$this->load->view()` call. In this case, if you want the variable to be named `data`, you'll have to pass in an array with the element key being `data` and the value being the data you retrieved from the model.

```
$data = array('data' => $this->userdata_model->desc($id));
$this->load->view('category/description', $data);
```

Comment: it works but still shows error .. undefined varibale data in views page

Comment: It works but it still shows the error? That doesn't make any sense. Could you explain what you mean by that? Is the error exactly the same? Or is it an error caused by a different undefined variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
 $data["ids"] = $this->userdata_model->desc($id);
 $this->load->view('category/description', $data);
```

in your view you can access the variable using

```
$ids
```

Answer (score 0):

`$data` is an array, contains all information, which you want show on view page.

In controller:

```
$this->load->model( 'userdata_model' );
// .. other code
$data = array(
        'description' => $this->userdata_model->desc($id)
    );
$this->load->view('category/description', $data );
```

In view:

```
<div><?php echo $description; ?></div>
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: description

Filename: category/description.php

Line Number: 1 . it gives this error. also i got result for array

Comment: In your code i see 2 view code calls: `$this->load->view('category/description' );` and `$this->load->view('category/description', $data );`, Remove first. When it called first time, no `$data` passed in view. In second call `$data` array passed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Because you call your View before call model, remove that row, and almost be good

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
$this->load->library('session');
$this->load->model('your model');
$data['Posts'] = $this->YourModel->ModelMethod();
$this->load->view('Your view', $data);
```

In your view foreach like this

```
<?php foreach($Posts as $item): ?>
  <?= item['id']   ;?> Or if you have STD Class <?= item->id   ;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```